# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Take off must be called before shared()

Tags: android, push-notification

I am upgrading my urban airship from 3.0 version to 8.3.0. I was converting my eclipse project to android studio project. I was getting the issue which is in the above.I Implemented the app in the android studio with the changes told in the latest urban airship SDK.

Comment: Where are you calling takeOff()? Are you using [AutoPilot](https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/Autopilot.html)?

Comment: I tried calling the takeOff() in the application and the oncreate() of the activity launcher.